# Using non-standard attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble passing around values without using global variables when I am creating html/jquery applications. Quick example

1) Load a table with a class such as "playersTable"

2) Attach a unique ID such as "25"

3) Click on the table row and spawn a row of buttons that will perform actions based on the parent's class and ID; such as query playersTable WHERE row = 25, etc.

The issue is that, as I am developing, I need to tie more and more values to the parent element (or any element that already has a class and ID) and I want to avoid adding 20 things to the class

I don't know what to do when I need to attach even more data to my elements. I have also made use of the attribute "value" but then I wonder if all browsers support it, if it's bad practice, etc. Does it even work if I just start creating my own attributes? Such as

```
<div id = "2" class = "test" myAttr = "foo"></div>
```

Or am I going about this all the wrong way in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing *why* you need to attach all that data to DOM elements it's hard to give concrete advice.

First, I'd consider using `data-` attributes.

Second, I'd consider using jQuery's `data()` method if you're attaching the data dynamically.

Third, I'd consider what data you actually need, and when.

Fourth, and probably most importantly, the ID attribute probably isn't really what you want to be setting.

Use a `data-id` element and get the ID that way; a simple numeric value isn't a valid ID. Unless you actually need to refer to the DOM element by ID, why bother? Usually what you really need is to just look up (or down) the nearby hierarchy and find the parent row etc. to pull out a single value, like `data("id")`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. However one issue I have is that I am populating my webpages with data from PHP. I was attaching data to things like Id and Class because that's the only way I saw to transfer things like primary key's to the html for jQuery to use.

Comment: Attaching data server side to use in JavaScript is *exactly* the use case data- attributes in HTML were designed for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to [use data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), either with pure JavaScript `element.dataset.some_attr_name` or with jQuery `element.data('some_attr_name')`.

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/dataset

jQuery data docs: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: It looks like I would be alienating IE10 and down users, though. What in the world does partial support mean?

Comment: @user3822370 Data attributes will work with deprecated versions of Internet Explorer, just not the JavaScript dataset methods. If you use getAttribute or the jQuery.attr() methods, this will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more precise when you say JavaScript dataset methods?

Comment: Does that mean I cannot do: var x = $('#div').data().... and access it via x.data ?